# Pass parametric type as a type argument to another type in TypeScript or Flow

Tags: typescript, flowtype, typescript-generics, higher-kinded-types, higher-order-types

For the purposes of demonstration, consider the following types:

```
type ToEnglish<A extends string> = 
  A extends "1" ? "one" :
  A extends "2" ? "two" :
  A extends "3" ? "three" :
  "etc";

type Convert<A extends string> =
  A extends `${infer C}${infer Tail}` ? 
    `${ToEnglish<C>}-${Convert<Tail>}` : "";
```

So for example, `Convert<"12">` results in `"one-two-"`.

Now I would like to make it *more generic* and accept a "translator" such as `ToEnglish` above as an argument:

```
type Convert2<A extends string, Translator> =
  A extends `${infer C}${infer Tail}` ? 
    `${Translator<C>}-${Convert<Tail>}` : "";
```

This won't work: `Type 'Translator' is not generic. ts(2315)`

If I try to write:

```
type Convert3<A extends string, Translator<_>> =
```

I get: `',' expected. ts(1005)` at the `<_>`.

**Q**:
Is there a way to pass a parametric (generic) type as an argument (parameter) to another type somehow in TypeScript, Flow, or another JavaScript superset?
Similar to higher-order functions, but for types.

Comment: TS does not support higher kinded types. AFAIK Flow.js does

Comment: I might change to Flow for this, let me change the question to also include Flow @captain-yossarian

Comment: While you can pass type constructor as generic to type utility https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap flowjs does not support template literal strings

Comment: @captain-yossarian, Hm, it doesn't seem to work for me: `type Test<N, F> = F<N>`, error is `Cannot apply type because it is not a polymorphic type. [nonpolymorphic-type-app]`

Comment: You need to use objectmap util type

Comment: Ok but how? I would like to have a type that takes an unapplied parametric type and then applies it.

Comment: Second argument of $ObjMap

Comment: Could you post an example? Let's say a type that takes a number literal type and an arithmetic type function, and returns the number type that is the result of applying that type function to the input? It doesn't look like `$ObjMap` applies its types

Comment: I have posted a pseudo answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a solution that bypasses having to pass the generic type as a type parameter directly. For instance, by using what is essentially a record of translators, you can instead pass the name of a given translator and access the type:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gUQHYHMA2BLAzgCwDwCCUEAHsBEgCZZRbABOGqAfFALxQBQUURp5VGgCIAjEKgB%20KELhII4gFzdexMhWrSATOKlDgAdziLlfNYOkBmHdOA56EeVCU8hEYAGMhAbk6dQkWDgAZTAAQyRsfFMBDTpGFnYuHmj1YTFJaQBXJCMnE1UY4W0MoUo4LGNkgtTLaz17CryXN08fX39oGHpwrDRQ4Dh6AFlQsEJq8zimFFYOAG9lHmR0SIVA5cxcQmYfHh4Q8NXAg4itgh3OAF928GgAYVkANwh6YABxCheMd3H%20GqnUAAaWDdJC9fqDCYaADWEBAcAAZiCen0BsNRttZvk-uYAAYAEjmTARLygd0uhOJpJgoQwaEuuIyiygBLmXRREPRYzuzAA2uywajBgBdS4AWkJDyQz1eHzkjB%20NLpwIF4LRzAZTmk3huAQ2kRgEDoiSlMvenwVeFE2mBQn1uCEzD8tygJwNRuAJqeL3N8u%20VpENukbodTs4QA)

```
type ToEnglish<A extends string> = 
  A extends "1" ? "one" :
  A extends "2" ? "two" :
  A extends "3" ? "three" :
  "etc";

type ToSpanish<A extends string> = 
  A extends "1" ? "uno" :
  A extends "2" ? "dos" :
  A extends "3" ? "tres" :
  "etc";


type TranslatorMap<A extends string> = {
    English: ToEnglish<A>;
    Spanish: ToSpanish<A>;
}

type ConvertGeneric<A extends string, Translator extends keyof TranslatorMap<A>> =
  A extends `${infer C}${infer Tail}` ? 
    `${TranslatorMap<C>[Translator]}-${ConvertGeneric<Tail, Translator>}` : "";

type EnglishTest = ConvertGeneric<"12", "English">
type SpanishTest = ConvertGeneric<"12", "Spanish">
```

Comment: This is a smart workaround, thank you. And it looks like there's no better way to do this currently in TS :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer to the question. Just a `flowjs` example:

```
// @flow

type TypeConstructor = <V>() => {updated:V};

type Obj = {
  a: number,
  b: string
}

type Result = $ObjMap<Obj, TypeConstructor>

const ok:Result = {
  a: {updated:42},
  b: {updated:42}
}; // ok

const error:Result = {
  a: 42,
  b: 42
}; // error
```

As you might have noticed, `TypeConstructor` is like callback.

It retrieves a `type` and converts it to another `type`. Each `obj` key/value pair is passed to `TypeConstructor`. It is impossible to do in TypeScript because TypeScript requires explicit generic for `TypeConstructor`.

Comment: So, `TypeConstructor` is not a parametric type and also not a type function, it's "output" is constant, doesn't depend on its parameters. In my examples, `ToEnglish` for example, is a "type function": depending on what type is passed to it in a parameter, it returns different resulting types.